# HGST 6TB Drive not recognized

Tags: debian, hard-disk, dmesg

I have a HP Proliant Microserver Gen8 running Debian Stretch. I installed a HGST 6TB HDD in Slot 1 and when I boot the device does not show.

```
dmesg
```

output:

```
[ 8.159512] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 8.159964] ata1.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[ 8.161254] ata1.00: READ LOG DMA EXT failed, trying unqueued
[ 8.161256] ata1.00: failed to get Log Directory Emask 0x40
[ 8.161258] ata1.00: ATA-9: HGST HDN726060ALE614, APGNW7JH, max UDMA/133
[ 8.161260] ata1.00: 11721045168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
[ 8.161261] ata1.00: failed to enable Sense Data Reporting, Emask 0x40
[ 8.161267] ata1.00: failed to set xfermode (err_mask=0x40)
[ 8.161331] ata1: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
[ 8.161332] ata1.00: limiting speed to UDMA/133:PIO3
[ 13.589737] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 320) 
[ 13.589743] ata1.00: disabled
```

Any idea what this could be?

My 3TB WesterDigital Red work without any trouble in all bays.

Comment: But the drive works in another machine? What's the controller / `lspci`? Same issue with sysresccd or similar?

Comment: pspci gives "RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA RAID Controller (rev 05)"

The drive works in a USB bay or in my regular computer.

Comment: Do you use raid controller? If yes - this controoler are built-in or external?

Comment: Can you complete your post with motherboard model?

Comment: I cant find a spec of the mainboard. but the controller is a Smart Array B120i

Answer (score 0):

I quote from the specs:

> Maximum Storage Capacity
>
> Internal SATA 16.0TB (4 x 4TB)

Source: https://www.hpe.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04128132.pdf

Comment: Thx i totally overlooked that. Well i supposed that means i have to get a new controller.

Comment: I dont think so. There are people that have drives larger than 4TB with other controllers in this server.

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling the IOMMU in BIOS.

I had the same problem with two WD Red 6 TB HDDs. They were "invisible" until I disabled the IOMMU (should be disabled by default on new devices).